# Allowing an image to extend outside column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to accomplish something in Bootstrap 3. I have two columns (unequal width) and I am trying to make image on right-side column and image on left-side column go all the way through (to the right edge of the viewport and the left edge of viewport respectively). How to accomplish this?

http://www.bootply.com/m0vFgSR9tM

I want both these images to extend all the way to cover screen though.

Things I tried:

1) Fluid row and fluid container: But they divide the entire viewport into 12 columns and that messes up my calculation even for this specific row so I still want to use container and row.

2) Negative margin. But I had to use `background:cover` because the image did not go all the way through,  but the result was very unpleasant because it compensated for the entire negative margin.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```css
.background1 {
    background-image:url('http://i.ytimg.com/vi/wMOpMka6PJI/maxresdefault.jpg');
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
}
.background2 {
    background-image:url('http://www.usc.edu/dept/engineering/summerprograms/assets/001/75466.gif');
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
}
.row .nopadding {
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 nopadding">
            <div class="background1">Test</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 nopadding">
            <div class="background2">Test</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, as mentioned, using container-fluid messes up my column calculation for that row. http://www.bootply.com/7OkBroYutm. See second image needs to start where black div is starting. Do you see what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to not mess with the grid I'm working with, and instead apply modification classes to interior elements.

```
.background1, .background2 {
    ...
    background-size: cover;
}
.edgy {
    margin: 0 -15px;
}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="background1 edgy">Test</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="background2 edgy">Test</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/fu3EvAESqF)**

Comment: No, as mentioned, using container-fluid messes up my column calculation for that row. bootply.com/7OkBroYutm. See second image needs to start where black div is starting. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: I don't know what "calculation" you're referring to, but you should simply not use a container for that row.

Comment: The starting point of the second image is based on container's column's starting point. If I use container-fluid, the starting point of the second image starts much earlier.